# Url mapping in django 2.0

Tags: python, django

so moving from Django 1.9 to Django 2 is not so smooth for me. I have struck in the URL patterns.

Django 2.0 uses `path` instead of URL, How to convert these URL patterns to Django 2.0 compatible?

`url(r'^post/(?<pk>\d+)$',)views.PostDetailView.as_view(), name ='post_detail'),`

`url('account/login/', views.login, name ='login')`

Thanks

Comment: The old syntax still works fine. You don't have to migrate to `path()`.

Comment: And even if you did, these are the simplest possible patterns; the docs cover them completely. What is not clear?

Comment: Django did not *remove* the `url(..)`, it just introduced a new `path(..)` since most such URLs have very similar constructs, and `path(..)`s aim to provide more clean (and semantical) syntax for that.

Comment: But I want to know the updated patterns, Dear

Comment: You can take a look at the documentation, that explains it quite well: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/http/urls/#how-django-processes-a-request

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Method-1

By using [**`path()`**](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/urls/#path)

```
from django.urls import path

urlpatterns = [
    path('post/<int:pk>/', views.PostDetailView.as_view(), name='post_detail'),
    path('account/login/', views.login, name='login')
]
```

### Method-2

You can use [**`re_path()`**](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/urls/#re-path) which behave same as **`url()`** does

```
from django.urls import re_path

urlpatterns = [
    re_path(r'^post/(?<pk>\d+)$', views.PostDetailView.as_view(), name='post_detail'),
    re_path(r'account/login/', views.login, name='login')
]
```

### Method-3

From the doc, ([What’s new in Django 2.0](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/releases/2.0/#simplified-url-routing-syntax))

> The `django.conf.urls.url()` function from previous versions is now available as `django.urls.re_path()`. The old location remains for backwards compatibility, without an imminent deprecation. The old `django.conf.urls.include()` function is now importable `from django.urls` so you can use **`from django.urls import include, path, re_path`** in your URLconfs.

So, you could use the same **`url()`** function in `django 2.x` (till the complete deprication) from the older location, as

```
from django.conf.urls import url

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^post/(?<pk>\d+)$', views.PostDetailView.as_view(), name='post_detail'),
    url('account/login/', views.login, name='login')
]
```

Comment: Sir can you tell me what is the difference between use re_path and this ```path('post/<int:pk>', views.PostDetailView.as_view(), name ='post_detail'),```

Comment: there is no difference. `path()` is much suitable in your context. But, if you need complex `expression`, you can use **`re_path()`**.

Comment: @Abhijeet Pal updated the answer with **`path()`** fucntion

Comment: Thank you so much sir, I wish I could upvote it but I can't.

Comment: @Abhijeet Pal You can mark the answer (`tick`) if your problem solved :)

Answer (score 2):

[Django 2.0 release notes](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/releases/2.0/#what-s-new-in-django-2-0) covers your case (not exactly, but anyway) - your urls could be rewritten as follows (assuming you meant `(?P<pk>\d+)` - note the `P` just after `?`):

```
path('post/<int:pk>/', views.PostDetailView.as_view(), name='post_detail'),
path('account/login/', views.login, name='login')
```

Comment: BTW sir does django 2.0 don't support kwargs? coz this line is throwing syntax error - ```path('account/logout/', views.logout, name ='logout', kwargs = { 'next_page':/})```

Comment: `SyntaxError` means there is something wrong with your syntax. In your case you should pass `'/'` (a string) not just `/`